# Using DictReader to read a csv file that contains a variable number of fields that have the same fieldname

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dictionary

Using DictReader and given a file that contains data like so:

```
First ,Last,fruit,fruit,fruit,fruit,fruit,fruit
Carl,Yung,apple,watermelon,,,,
Louis,Pasteur,banana,grape,mango,,,
Marie,Curie,watermelon,apple,banana,,,
```

How do I assign any non-empty "fruit" fields to a list so that when the following code executes, `row['fruit']` contains that list.

```
with open(csv_file) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row['First'],row['Last'],row['fruit'], sep='--->')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If fieldnames is omitted, the values in the first row will be used as the fieldnames.  *But you may specify it explicitly.* If a row has more fields than fieldnames, the remaining data is put in a list and stored with the fieldname specified by `restkey` (which defaults to `None`).

```
import csv

with open("myfile.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=("First", "Last"), restkey="fruit")
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```